# CustomPainter Redraw with Listenable

Tags: flutter, dart

The CustomPainter class seems to a few ways to trigger a repaint.

I've got my painter working with the shouldRepaint method, however, i'd like my painter to react to changes in a listenable instead of polling for changes.

The Flutter documentation states that

> The most efficient way to trigger a repaint is to either:
>
> Extend this class and supply a repaint argument to the constructor of > the CustomPainter, where that object notifies its listeners when it is time to repaint.
>   Extend Listenable (e.g. via ChangeNotifier) and implement CustomPainter, so that the object itself provides the notifications directly.

I have tried passing in the listenable to the Custom Painter however when the listenable updates, the paint method is not called as is stated in the docs

> In either case, the CustomPaint widget or RenderCustomPaint render object will listen to the Listenable and repaint whenever the animation ticks,

```dart
class CursorPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Listenable _repaint;
  Player player;
  BuildContext context;

  // Pass in repaint (listenable)
  CursorPainter({repaint, this.context}) {
    _repaint = repaint;
    player = Provider.of<Player>(context, listen: false);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  // Paint logic...
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CursorPainter lastTrackPainter) {
     // Tried returning both true and false here to no avail. Method is continually called.
  }
}
```

I'd expect that each time the listenable changes and calls notifyListeners() that the CustomPainter would repaint itself as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your constructor, call `super`,...

```
  CursorPainter({Listenable repaint, this.context}) : super(repaint: repaint) {
    _repaint = repaint;
    player = Provider.of<Player>(context, listen: false);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. Works exactly as advertised.

Comment: Although the paint methods are called at the expected intervals (when the change notifier calls notifylisteners() It seems that the should repaint function is still called at 60 x per second. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Nope. Looks like its ok. The shouldRepaint methods aren't called.

Comment: Are you sure `super(repaint: repaint);` call be called as a statement in the constructor body? In my case I get a compiler error: `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function`.

Comment: You are correct it should be an initializer. Updated answer.