# Flutter: How to notify CustomPainter to redraw?

Tags: flutter

In the following code I attempt to simulate widgets on the canvas.

[image: three buttons]

When a widget/button is touched, it flips between two colors.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() { runApp(MyApp()); }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Diagram',
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.blueAccent,),
      ),
      home: Diagram(),
    );
  }
}

class Diagram extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiagramState createState() => new _DiagramState();
}

class _DiagramState extends State<Diagram> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Canvas Widgets'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            setState(() {
                ;
            });
          },
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.0,
            child: Container(
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: DiagramPainter(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter {
// class DiagramPainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter {
  DiagramPainter() {
    for(int i=0; i<_numberOfButtons; i++) {
      state.add(false);
    }
  }

  static final int _numberOfButtons = 3;
  static final double _margin = 60;
  static final double _gap = _margin / 2.0 / _numberOfButtons.toDouble();
  double width;
  double y;

  static Canvas currentCanvas;

  var buttons = [];
  var state = [];

  final bluePaint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue;
  final yellowPaint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.yellow;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    currentCanvas = canvas;
    width = (size.width - _margin) /_numberOfButtons.toDouble();
    y = size.height / 2.0 - width / 2.0;

    Iterable<int>.generate(_numberOfButtons).toList().forEach((index) {
      buttons.add(drawButton(canvas, index));
    });
  }

  Rect drawButton(Canvas canvas, int index) {
    double left = _gap + index * (width + _gap * 2.0);

    var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(left, y, width, width);
    var paint = state[index] ? yellowPaint : bluePaint;
    canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
    return rect;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    for(int i=0; i<_numberOfButtons; i++) {
      if (buttons[i].contains(position)) {
        state[i] = !state[i];
        // trigger redraw
        // notifyListeners();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

I gathered that I need to `class DiagramPainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter` rather than `class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter`.

I also gathered that I need to trigger a redraw through `notifyListeners()`. Who is being notified in this case? It continues to be `DiagramPainter`, no? What am I missing?

Related:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262727/how-to-notify-android-widget-to-redraw),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57633554/custompainter-redraw-with-listenable).

Comment: either 1) pass `Listenable` to [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html) constructor (via optional `repaint` named parameter) or 2) `class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter with ChangeNotifier` and call `notifyListeners()` when needed

Comment: @pskink Well, I am in fact looking for a fully dynamic set of widgets in a canvas. So :-) either 1) I accept Chunhunghan's answer, which is perfectly fine given the way I wrote the present question, and ask a sequel or 2) you show us the details (the devil _is_ in the details) by writing an answer.

Comment: @pskink I think 2) is better, because we then have the two techniques back-to-back to study and compare.

Comment: @pskink Complete with corrections for many code smells. Nice!

Comment: @pskink I see several advantages in your code, but I'm still stumped. How does the mere presence of the `ChangeNotifier` mixin make `notifyListeners()` invoke `paint()`? Is, for example, `paint()` declared somehow to be the to-be-notified-upon-change agent for `CustomPainter`?

Comment: "How does the mere presence of the ChangeNotifier mixin make notifyListeners() invoke paint()?" - this is magic ;-), ok the docs say something like this: "Extend Listenable (e.g. via ChangeNotifier) and implement CustomPainter, so that the object itself provides the notifications directly." and it results with a code you posted `class DiagramPainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter` but it needs 6 methods to be implemented and i think everybody assumes its a docs bug and does not even try to go that way - if you really want to know how it works check `RenderCustomPaint` sources

Comment: this is the most important place: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/v0.9.2/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart#485  - you can override `void addListener(listener) {` in your custom painter and call `print(listener);` to see what is passed as a parameter

Comment: @pskink Great advice throughout. It does look a bit like magic. I like magic, provided a clue appears _somewhere_ in the client (and not just the library) code. If no clue is visible, it starts to seem that the fabric of the language is deficient. It'd be too bad, really, given so much spirit and so much elegance. I see that you're here for the love of knowledge about programming, rather than to participate in the trade of this odd currency SO is peddling. Moving on. Next exercise: how to trigger an AnimationController from a ChangeNotifier.

Comment: that magic is because the google guys dont say anything about how they trigger the update internally: if they said that `CustomPainter.addListener` is called by `RenderCustomPaint` a lot of thing would be easier, but what they say instead? `Extend Listenable (e.g. via ChangeNotifier) and implement CustomPainter, so that the object itself provides the notifications directly.` - to me it does not really say much - i had to dive into the sources and spend half an hour to see how to make things working, and for the "next exercise": - what you mean by that? what `AnimationController`?

Comment: @pskink Consider this: we don't just want to change each widget's color. We want to change other attributes. Say each widget is a bead in a (binary) abacus. It displays its status using its position (up/down). We can continue to handle onTapDown, but users are demanding. They want to see the bead moving. Now the question is whether handling onVerticalDragStart and onVerticalDragUpdate (rather than onTapDown) are enough, or some heavier guns (such as AnimationController) are needed.

Comment: If they have to move on its own (for example you clicked one bead and want it to move up) then yes, you need  `AnimationController`

Comment: and if you really need such dynamically changing layout it would be better to use widgets (and not custom painter) - otherwise you would need to track the position of your bead when implementing the gesture detector's logic (tapped / dragged etc)

Comment: @pskink One way or the other it's necessary to handle GestureDetector's methods at a fine granularity, because when looking at an abacus, the user is surely interested in playing with the beads, by touching one and moving it slightly, but not yet flicking it. Then onVerticalStart/Update() will confirm to the user that they do have control over the beads. If onTapUp is detected past a threshold, a bead travels the rest of the trip on its own, via AnimationController.

Comment: @pskink Of course a simpler tap handler can do it, but each bead would look and behave like an implementation of a checkbox. The older method that Apple used to unlock iOS devices is the way to go.

Comment: @pskink If you agree that GestureDetector's fine granularity is needed anyway, then CustomPainter is more useful, because it would enable the drawing of an abacus's frame and rods, perhaps on separate layers. Doing the same using just widgets is possible, but it would be a pain to guarantee how it'll all look on different devices and different (portrait/landscape) orientations.

Comment: so you will be surprised how `AnimationController` could he useful here, (i myself did not know it till yesterday or so), check https://gist.github.com/pskink/9473bff3b37d171332a0aeaedfef5bd8, here you can have 3 animations: 1) simple tup down + tup up on the bead, 2) tup down, drag it and release in the middle (when velocity is 0 or almost 0) and 3) tup down, drag it and release (when velocity is above some threshold - some people call it fling) - with the last one i had some problems since i had to multiply `kMinFlingVelocity` by 10 - see line #85 - if you dont do that the fling always wins

Comment: @pskink You almost make it look too easy. You're more than two notches ahead of me so I need to work harder to narrow the gap and be able, if not to replicate right away, to appreciate all the subtleties of your code. What's really cool though is that all the wizardry that Mike Bostock exhibits in his D3.js demos (such as force-directed graph drawing) may very well be already doable within the flutter api, and with a codebase that is not that much longer than the one needed using D3.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually the code i gave you was buggy as it required a sized parent, i simply solved it by wrapping everything with `SizedBox(width: 64, ...)` - see [here](https://gist.github.com/pskink/9473bff3b37d171332a0aeaedfef5bd8#file-foo_anim_ctrl-dart-L40) - so now you can use it as: `child: Center(
child: Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
border: Border.all(color: Colors.teal, width: 2),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
color: Colors.white54,
),
child: Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
FooAnimCtrl(),
FooAnimCtrl(),
FooAnimCtrl(),
],
),
),
),`

Comment: and as for D3 i was not aware of it till now, it is really cool stuff ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: `DiagramPainter({Listenable repaint}) : super(repaint: repaint)` 
Step 2: Pass `ValueNotifier<int>(0);` to `DiagramPainter(repaint: _counter)` 
Step 4: In `onTapUp` call `_counter.value++;` 
code snippet

```
class _DiagramState extends State<Diagram> {
  final _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            _counter.value++;               
          },
          child: ...
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: DiagramPainter(repaint: _counter),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter {    
  DiagramPainter({Listenable repaint}) : super(repaint: repaint) {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Diagram',
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
      ),
      home: Diagram(),
    );
  }
}

class Diagram extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiagramState createState() => new _DiagramState();
}

class _DiagramState extends State<Diagram> {
  final _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Canvas Widgets'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            _counter.value++;
            /*setState(() {
              ;
            });*/
          },
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.0,
            child: Container(
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: DiagramPainter(repaint: _counter),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter {
// class DiagramPainter extends ChangeNotifier implements CustomPainter {
  DiagramPainter({Listenable repaint}) : super(repaint: repaint) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfButtons; i++) {
      state.add(false);
    }
  }

  static final int _numberOfButtons = 3;
  static final double _margin = 60;
  static final double _gap = _margin / 2.0 / _numberOfButtons.toDouble();
  double width;
  double y;

  static Canvas currentCanvas;

  var buttons = [];
  var state = [];

  final bluePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
  final yellowPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.yellow;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    currentCanvas = canvas;
    width = (size.width - _margin) / _numberOfButtons.toDouble();
    y = size.height / 2.0 - width / 2.0;

    Iterable<int>.generate(_numberOfButtons).toList().forEach((index) {
      buttons.add(drawButton(canvas, index));
    });
  }

  Rect drawButton(Canvas canvas, int index) {
    double left = _gap + index * (width + _gap * 2.0);

    var rect = Rect.fromLTWH(left, y, width, width);
    var paint = state[index] ? yellowPaint : bluePaint;
    canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
    return rect;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfButtons; i++) {
      if (buttons[i].contains(position)) {
        state[i] = !state[i];
        // trigger redraw
        // notifyListeners();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Credit and up-vote to @chunhunghan for the answer. In case it helps someone else, I've put in some new code here, updated for the latest flutter, simplified a bit, and with some comments.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// based on @chunhunghan in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327785/flutter-how-to-notify-custompainter-to-redraw

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Diagram',
      home: Diagram(),
    );
  }
}

class Diagram extends StatefulWidget {
  const Diagram({super.key});

  @override
  DiagramState createState() => DiagramState();
}

class DiagramState extends State<Diagram> {

  final _counter = ValueNotifier<int>(0);  // 1. the important bit

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Canvas Widgets'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height:300,
          child: GestureDetector(
          onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
            _counter.value++; // 2. another important bit
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: DiagramPainter(notifier: _counter),
          ),
        )),
    );
  }
}

class DiagramPainter extends CustomPainter {
  // 3. constructor has, and passes to super, the listenable - the final important bit
  DiagramPainter({required this.notifier}) : super(repaint: notifier);
  // Keeping the notified as a variable here is not required, unless you
  // are interested in the notified data.
  // Passing the notifier to super is sufficient to get the repaint 
  // on every change of the object inside ValueNotifier
  ValueNotifier<int> notifier;
  var _state = false;
  final bluePaint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
  final yellowPaint = Paint()..color = Colors.yellow;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print("counter has value = ${notifier.value}");
    _drawButton(canvas);
  }

  void _drawButton(Canvas canvas) {
    var rect = const Rect.fromLTWH(100, 100, 100, 100);
    var paint = _state ? yellowPaint : bluePaint;
    _state = !_state;
    canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```